# Jupyter notebook toolbar issue

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda 5.0.1 with Python 3.6.3, however when I start Jupyter notebook, the toolbar does not show the symbols as shown in the attached picture: [image: Jupyter Notebook Toolbar Issue]
The system is Windows 10, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of issue with you.
my OS is Win-10,python version is 3.6/3.5
I click the 'View' button,and choose the 'toolbar',it shows nothing.
I've no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out something wrong with the OS. The issue is solved after reinstall the OS.